# Python - Convert Oracle time to Date and Time of Day

Tags: python, csv, time

I'm working on a script that pulls some columns from a very large .xls file. One of those columns is "InviteTime (Oracle)"  - here are some examples of the time.

```
08:54.2
49:15.9
```

I don't understand Oracle time - I see that excel can simply convert this into

```
2/10/2014  2:08:54 PM
2/10/2014  1:49:16 PM
```

But I'm not sure how, and I'm not sure if Python has a useful module for doing this. I've looked in Google and found some informaton on strftime() but it doesn't seem to do what I need.

Here is the actual code from my program

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Python27\\Work\\testsheet.csv')

time = df["InviteTime (Oracle)"]
orignum = df["Orig Number"]
origip = df["Orig IP Address"]
destnum = df["Dest Number"]


print time 
print orignum 
print origip 
print destnum
```

All suggestions are welcome, thank you!

Comment: `08:54.2` is literally how it's coming out in your CSV file? Depending what you want to do - you could read the sheet directly from excel using some 3rd party modules... (pandas does support reading excel files as well... so...)

Comment: What do you mean by "excel can simply convert this"? Is there a "right-click -> convert to datetime" option? Is there a "datetime" column to the right of "InviteTime (Oracle)" whose formula appears to access it?

Comment: Can you provide some more time examples? What is the Oracle time for 4:08:15 AM on July 16th, 2342?

Comment: In execl I can simply highlight those oracle dates I posted, and "Format Cells" with "Date" and then choose any of the date/time formats.